# Why does MySQL think I'm using SRID 1?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, spatial

I can run the query on my local machine no problem (Server version: 10.4.6-MariaDB), but when I run it on my remote one (Server version: 8.0.17 MySQL) it poops out this error message:

`ERROR 3548 (SR001): There's no spatial reference system with SRID 1.`

Here's my query:

```sql
SELECT c.cd116fp 
FROM spat.cb_2019_us_cd116_500k c 
WHERE ST_Contains(c.SHAPE, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-78.8768302 42.8776271)', 4269))
```

Here's the contents of those special tables:

```sql
mysql> select * from geometry_columns ;
+-----------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------+---------+
| F_TABLE_CATALOG | F_TABLE_SCHEMA | F_TABLE_NAME          | F_GEOMETRY_COLUMN | COORD_DIMENSION | SRID | TYPE    |
+-----------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------+---------+
| NULL            | NULL           | cb_2019_36_sldl_500k  | SHAPE             |               2 | 4269 | POLYGON |
| NULL            | NULL           | cb_2019_36_sldu_500k  | SHAPE             |               2 | 4269 | POLYGON |
| NULL            | NULL           | cb_2019_us_cd116_500k | SHAPE             |               2 | 4269 | POLYGON |
+-----------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```sql
mysql> select * from spatial_ref_sys;
+------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SRID | AUTH_NAME | AUTH_SRID | SRTEXT                                                                                                                       |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 4269 | NULL      |      NULL | GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]] |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

These shapes were imported with ogr2ogr on my local machine and the SRIDs were set originally as 1, but I changed them to 4269 after searching through the `information_schema` `st_spatial_reference_system` for (what I believe to be) the proper SRID.

The similarity of srs_id 4269 to the one that was placed in my database by ogr2ogr can be seen here:

```sql
mysql> select * from st_spatial_reference_systems where `srs_id`=4269;
+----------+--------+--------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| SRS_NAME | SRS_ID | ORGANIZATION | ORGANIZATION_COORDSYS_ID | DEFINITION                                | DESCRIPTION |
+----------+--------+--------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| NAD83    |   4269 | EPSG         |                     4269 | GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North American Datum 1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[1,1,-1,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.017453292519943278,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Lat",NORTH],AXIS["Lon",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]] | NULL        |
+----------+--------+--------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I changed the SRIDs in my `geometry_columns` from `1` to `4269` after it gave me the error message, thinking it would correct the error, but to my amazement, it STILL says `SRID 1 ain't there`.  On my local machine the query works using SRID 1 or 4269.  After I uploaded it, I only get the above error, no matter what SRID I specify.  I'm not sure if I was supposed to change it or not but that was my feeble attempt at troubleshooting.

The database is taken from the [census.gov](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html) shape files.

I've normally been able to fudge my way through a basic spatial query but could someone point me in the right direction please?

Update:
I just learned "With MySQL 8.0 or later, the ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS table provided by the database is used instead of spatial_ref_sys."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were only two things I needed to do for the query to work:

1.) Set the SRID of each geometry object in the table.  I did not understand that this information was stored here.

```sql
UPDATE spat.cb_2019_us_cd116_500k SET `SHAPE`=ST_SRID(`SHAPE`,4269);
```

2.) Reverse the order of the Latitude and Longitude in my queries.  Latitude apparently must come first in MySQL 8 (or at least with the specific SRID of 4269).

```sql
SELECT c.cd116fp 
FROM spat.cb_2019_us_cd116_500k c 
WHERE ST_Contains(c.SHAPE, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(42.8776271 -78.8768302)', 4269))
```

As noted already, MySQL 8 does not use the `spatial_ref_sys` table that was generated by ogr2ogr.  For the query to work, I didn't need to update the `geometry_columns` table either so perhaps that is equally vestigial.